# What's the /path/to/initial/clusters parameter means in Mahout 0.5 kmeans example?

Tags: mahout

I tried to run the kmeans example in Mahout 0.5, but failed! I found in kmeans.props that it required a strange parameter, `-c`, which means `path_to_initial_clusters`.

What's this stuff? How could I prepare for it?

kmeans.props:

```
 The following parameters must be specified
i|input = /path/to/input
c|clusters = /path/to/initial/clusters
```

Answer (score 0):

So mahout cannot needs input in specific format to carry out its clustering algorithm.
So have a look at 
 seq2sparse: : Sparse Vector generation from Text sequence files
 seqdirectory: : Generate sequence files (of Text) from a directory

As an example say for Reuters 21587 data set.

Following are the steps :

1.mahout seqdirectory -c UTF-8
-i examples/reuters-extracted/ -o reuters-seqfiles

2.mahout seq2sparse -i reuters-seqfiles/ -o reuters-vectors -ow

3.mahout kmeans -i reuters-vectors/tfidf-vectors/ \
-c reuters-initial-clusters \
-o reuters-kmeans-clusters \
-dm org.apache.mahout.common.distance.SquaredEuclideanDistanceMeasure \
-cd 1.0 -k 20 -x 20 -cl

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

K-means requires initial clusters in order to iteratively update the centroid (which is the center of a cluster) until it converge.

-c, path_to_initial_clusters ask you just to give a directory for mahout to store its initial clusters.

You can specify any path for mahout to store the initial clusters and mahout will compute the initial clusters and store in the directory. Or you can compute the initial cluster by canopy clustering or other method, and tell mahout the directory of the initial cluster you have computed to initialize K-means clustering.